# Dynamic modals using Bootstrap 5.0.0 and Webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

Since Bootstrap 5.0.0, it seems Bootstrap JS file must be loaded at the end of the `<body>` in order to render dynamically loaded Modals (and maybe other features). Check [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33840)

> Agree with this issue. This happens in bootstrap 5.x production release irrespective of how you initialize the modal. Either dynamically via JS or via Data attributes.
>
> Currently the workaround to overcome this issue is to load the `bootstrap.bundle.js` within the HTML body and not in the head. But it ideally cannot be the solution to this issue.

Do you know another workaround for this issue ?

---

Error:

```js
// Error happens when I want to display a Modal using JS

var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('my-modal');
modal.show();

// Uncaught TypeError: BACKDROP: Option "rootElement" provided type "null" but expected type "element".
//    typeCheckConfig bootstrap.bundle.js:190
//    typeCheckConfig bootstrap.bundle.js:184
//    _getConfig bootstrap.bundle.js:4603
//    Backdrop bootstrap.bundle.js:4539
//    _initializeBackDrop bootstrap.bundle.js:4864
//    Modal bootstrap.bundle.js:4721
//    <anonymous> debugger eval code:2
```

---

A solution:

Simplest workaround is to load our JS at the end of the `<body>` tag:

```html
# app/views/layout/application.html.erb

<body>
  <%= yield %>
  <%# this `javascript_pack_tag` is initially inside the `<head>` tag
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that the `#my-modal` doesn't exist when it comes to script evaluating? You don't have to place script at the end of body. You can wait until the [document is loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: Sadly it's the the issue here. If `#my-modal` does not exist, it raises a different error: `Uncaught TypeError: this._element is undefined`. In my code I trigger the Modal object instantiation and `show()` right after integrating it into the DOM (I can share more code if you think it's needed)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was using a class="container" div and chaged it to <div class="container-fluid" div and suddenly my modal didn't work anymore.

I'm using Bootstrap 5, and bootstrap.bundle.min.js is loaded in the header section of the html file.

My "workaround" with this problem was to put the "content-fluid" class div after the "modal" class div. To be perfectly honest I don't quite understand why does it work now, but it does

Hope it's usefull.